# How do I save an embedded image in Microsoft Access to a file?

Tags: image, ms-access, vba

I have a lot of images embedded in an Access database.  I need to save the images to a file.  How do I do this in VBA?

Comment: You could use  [ExtractInventoryOLE](http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `GetChunk` and `AppendChunk` functions.

Here are some MSDN pages about how to load and save images from Access databases:

- [How To Read and Write BLOBs Using GetChunk and AppendChunk](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;194975&x=15&y=14)
- [Reading, Storing, & Writing Binary Large Objects (BLOBs)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103257/en-us)

And here are [two example databases for Access 97 and 2000](http://accdevel.tripod.com/imaging.htm).
(You want the module `basBLOB` from in there - the code is based on the second MSDN page)

Answer (score 0):

OLE objects is bad way of storing images in MS Access.
Use OLEToDisk (http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm) to save your images as pic files.

After that reimport them in nice way. Check AccessImagine (http://access.bukrek.net) for working with images in Access - it does all the hard job.